# Android Sqlite question

Tags: android, sqlite

Does someone knows if the data saved in the SQLITE database stays there once you power off the device? if it doesn't how can i save that data so that when i turn the device back on is available for use
thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it does. But even if you used the Shared Preferences to save a couple of values, they will also be there after you reboot the device. So for application preference settings you can also use that without need for a database. But you should use a database for the data managed by your application, and yes it will be persistent and available after each device reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. Being a persistent store is its primary purpose.